# How to categorize adience data in age groups?

Tags: classification, face-recognition, face-detection

I am working on an Age estimation project using facial recognition and I am planning to use the adience dataset. I could not figure out how to create the training data for my dataset, do I need to put the images from the dataset manually into the different age groups? Or is the classified dataset available?

Answer (score 0):

I have got an easy way to classify the 20000 images in different age groups. Put them all in one folder and sort them according to their id and now refer to the text file given on adience website.